# Proper segue flow

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, segue, uistoryboardsegue

I am looking for the best-practice method of doing the following:

I have two TabBarController views embedded in a NavigationController and one which I don't want to include as a tab but is embedded in a NavigationController:

1. FeedView (TableViewController)
2. VenueView (CollectionViewController)
3. SelectView (ViewController)

In VenueView (2), I have the following code to bring up SelectView (3):

```
override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

let selectVC: SelectViewController! = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("selectVC") as! SelectViewController

selectVC.currentVenue = venueItems[indexPath.row]    
    presentViewController(selectVC, animated: true, completion: nil)

}
```

This segue works, however SelectView(3) doesn't have a navigation bar at the top although it is embedded in a separate NavigationController. If I hook it up to the other NavController in the IB, it adopts/becomes the third tab in the BarTabController. I don't want that.

How do I hook it up so that there is a NavBar (with a back button that will go back to either view) but no Tab?

Also, there is a button on SelectView(3). When this button is tapped I'd like it to segue to FeedView(1) - while persisting some data ie 'pushing into the feed'. What kind of segue should I use for this? I've tried many combinations and ran into some strange bugs and I find View management very confusing.

Storyboard image below for reference 
Views are in order from top to bottom (1-3):

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to do this you need to fix your problem, you need to present the navigation controller which contains `SelectView` but not `SelectView` itself as you do now.

You should set a storyboard identifier to your 3'rd navigation controller and apply this change:

```
let selectNavigationController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("selectNavigationController") as! UINavigationController
let selectVC = selectNavigationController.topViewController as! SelectViewController
selectVC.currentVenue = venueItems[indexPath.row]

presentViewController(selectNavigationController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: thanks for the reply - this was useful however i had to change `let selectVC = selectNavigationController.rootViewController as! SelectViewController`
 to `let selectVC = selectNavigationController.topViewController as! SelectViewController` because "UINavigationController" 'does not have a member named...'

Comment: I'm glad, it helped. Sorry for the mistake.